# Apache Ignite c++, Shared memory

Tags: c++, ignite, shared-objects

I'm new to Apache ignite, I have an application which runs in multi processes model. I'm trying to find an Ignite configuration in which I should be able to run only one server on a machine and use the same server node in my multi instances of c++ application to access the cache. I tried by just calling the Ignition::Get("SERVERNAME"), after starting the server on the same node. It worked only when the call was made from the same process where the server was instantiated, but other processes failed to get the Ignite instance.

I know we have a client approach, but the client performs very poorly. More over I'm looking for a shared memory approach, All my processes can use ignite as a shared memory cache on the same machine and replicate the data to other machine when needed.  Answer to this would be a great help for me thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can't do that. To get access to the grid from the other process you can currently use either ignite client or ODBC driver.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply, Which one would be faster. ODBC or ignite client. In case of ignite client it is starting a jvm internally, Will this hit on client performance?.

Comment: In general, no, Ignite client is not slower than ODBC driver. In fact, in some cases it can be a little faster. But there are some other concerns you may want to consider. 1 - It consumes more memory. 2 - as any other JVM application it needs to be "warmed up" before it gets really fast.